# Hive query fails if the data loaded exceeded 1GB

Tags: hadoop, hive, cluster-computing

I am having a set up of Hadoop-2.5.2 and Hive 0.14.0 I cerated a table with a customised Serde and it works for a simple `select * from tablename;`  query with "Load data local inpath" but if the input data exceeded 1GB then it fails. with this error:

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

I have searched for the error and have tried all the solutions I came across, but still problem persisted. Can someone help me out please.

Thank you in anticipation

Comment: Did you check Job application log from the history server?

Comment: ok where is that Job application log  be found? thank you

Comment: I'd bet that the problem is a bad record somewhere deep in your data that's causing the serde to fail.

Comment: @ maxymoo Thank you for the comment. Yes I though of that and I tried loading individual files and it always work if the total input size does not exceeded 1GB.

Comment: @UsmanAli I have run into what I think is exactly the same problem with Hadoop-2.6.0 and Hive-1.1.0.  Did you determine the cause?